# How to use external random number generator with java.security.KeyPairGenerator?

Tags: java, random, key-pair, secure-random

Basically I have a RNG providing random numbers into a database and I would like to use these random numbers when generating a key pair.

From my understanding so far, you can initialize the KeyPairGenerator providing a randomness source (SecureRandom object).
Looking into SecureRandom documentation, I only see the possibility to provide a seed that will be used as a "base" seed when generating a seed (method generateSeed()). Am I correct ?

Do I have to create my own implementation of SecureRandomSpi class where the generateSeed() method would basically return a random number picked from the database ?

I would appreciate advices from someone with experience in this matter.

Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can just subclass SecureRandom since it has an accessible no-args constructor. You should look at the source code for the bouncycastle library classes in package [`org.bouncycastle.crypto.prng`](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/crypto/prng/package-frame.html), in particular the [`FixedSecureRandom`](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/crypto/prng/FixedSecureRandom.java) class, for examples.

Comment: Thank you James for your answer and providing an example I can look into.
Lionel

Comment: Hi James,

I got back on this task and try a simple example by subclassing SecureRandom and only printing a specific message for every method .
Then I did the following test:
    `KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDSA", 
 "LunaProvider");
keyGen.initialize(P521EC(), new MySecureRandom());
keyPair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();`

The only logs I got on the console are:
`**setSeed(long)
**MySecureRandom constructor`

Reading SecureRandom javadoc, I was expected the method 
"nextBytes()" to be called but that is not the case.
Do you know why ?

Comment: LunaProvider? I'm sure that uses only internal randomizers and ignores any you provide.

Comment: On the [Luna SDK](https://cloudhsm-safenet-docs.s3.amazonaws.com/007-011136-002_lunasa_5-1_webhelp_rev-a/Content/sdk/s8_-_luna_jsp.htm) documentation, section "SecureRandom Objetcs", they say that it is possible to provide for example a PRNG. And that it won't use the Hardware RNG provided by the Luna HSM. It is exactly what I would like to do.
I will try contacting the customer support.

Comment: After some exchange with the support team, it turns out that it is a only possible to seed the Luna internal random number generator.
It is not possible to replace it by external random numbers.